# Operating on non-imported classes

Tags: java, javafx, import

my question is how can we operate in Java on objects of classes which are not imported in our program? Here is an example from my JavaFX application:

```
for(String item: participantsLabel.getItems())
```

this is my for loop, where `participantsLabel` is an object of class ListView (simply some sort of table, where we can store our elements). Method `getItems()` returns us a list (specifically an ObservableList object, which is an subclass of a List class) of elements contained in our `participantsLabel` object. So the point is - program dont see any errors - we can easily operate on our list without importing a List class. But when we want to for example assign this object to some variable, by creating:

```
ObservableList ourList = participantsLabel.getItems();
```

compilator shows us an error - we have to import an ObservedList class. Can someone explain me, how then we are interpreting our list in for loop, without importing its return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the compiler always writes the fully qualified class name to the bytecode it outputs. Imports are just syntactic sugar that allows you to use the class name without the package name of instead of the fully qualified name.

Imports are only needed, if you declare a variable of a type in your code, use it in a cast or use it to access `static` members or a constructor. Other types don't require imports, since the compiler is able to determine the type of an expression based on the declarations/signatures of the classes involved.

Using `javap` on a class file should provide some insight about the result of the compilation:

#### source code

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import java.util.ArrayList; // some unused import

public class SimpleProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(FXCollections.observableArrayList("a").get(0));
    }

}
```

#### `javap -v SimpleProgram.class`

```
[...]
public class SimpleProgram
  [...]
  this_class: #8                          // SimpleProgram
  super_class: #9                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 2, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #9.#23         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #24.#25        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   #3 = Class              #26            // java/lang/String
   #4 = String             #27            // a
   #5 = Methodref          #28.#29        // javafx/collections/FXCollections.observableArrayList:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavafx/collections/ObservableList;
   #6 = InterfaceMethodref #30.#31        // javafx/collections/ObservableList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   #7 = Methodref          #32.#33        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #8 = Class              #34            // SimpleProgram
   #9 = Class              #35            // java/lang/Object
  #10 = Utf8               <init>
  #11 = Utf8               ()V
  #12 = Utf8               Code
  #13 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #14 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #15 = Utf8               this
  #16 = Utf8               LSimpleProgram;
  #17 = Utf8               main
  #18 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #19 = Utf8               args
  #20 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
  #21 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #22 = Utf8               SimpleProgram.java
  #23 = NameAndType        #10:#11        // "<init>":()V
  #24 = Class              #36            // java/lang/System
  #25 = NameAndType        #37:#38        // out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #26 = Utf8               java/lang/String
  #27 = Utf8               a
  #28 = Class              #39            // javafx/collections/FXCollections
  #29 = NameAndType        #40:#41        // observableArrayList:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavafx/collections/ObservableList;
  #30 = Class              #42            // javafx/collections/ObservableList
  #31 = NameAndType        #43:#44        // get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  #32 = Class              #45            // java/io/PrintStream
  #33 = NameAndType        #46:#47        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #34 = Utf8               SimpleProgram
  #35 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #36 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #37 = Utf8               out
  #38 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #39 = Utf8               javafx/collections/FXCollections
  #40 = Utf8               observableArrayList
  #41 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavafx/collections/ObservableList;
  #42 = Utf8               javafx/collections/ObservableList
  #43 = Utf8               get
  #44 = Utf8               (I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  #45 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #46 = Utf8               println
  #47 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
{
  public SimpleProgram();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      [...]
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LSimpleProgram;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: iconst_1
         4: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/String
         7: dup
         8: iconst_0
         9: ldc           #4                  // String a
        11: aastore
        12: invokestatic  #5                  // Method javafx/collections/FXCollections.observableArrayList:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavafx/collections/ObservableList;
        15: iconst_0
        16: invokeinterface #6,  2            // InterfaceMethod javafx/collections/ObservableList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
        21: checkcast     #3                  // class java/lang/String
        24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        27: return
      [...]
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      28     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

First of all notice that there is no section that corresponds to the imports. `java.util.ArrayList` is completely missing and the names of all types/members used are stored in the constant pool.

```
   #6 = InterfaceMethodref #30.#31        // javafx/collections/ObservableList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  #30 = Class              #42            // javafx/collections/ObservableList
  #31 = NameAndType        #43:#44        // get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
[...]
  #41 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavafx/collections/ObservableList;
  #42 = Utf8               javafx/collections/ObservableList
[...]
16: invokeinterface #6,  2            // InterfaceMethod javafx/collections/ObservableList.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

This is the invocation of `ObservableList.get`. The method used is stored inside the constant pool and is determined by the compiler even though we didn't import it. It's just something the compiler does automatically.

You may notice that even types that don't require an import used with the fully qualified name:

```
   #9 = Class              #35            // java/lang/Object
  [...]
  #35 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
```

Answer (score 0):

In a value returned from a method call, it is clear from the method's (`getItems()`) signature which class should the compiler use.

On the contrary, when you use a (non-fully qualified) symbol, you need to import it. Or change it to fully qualified - then the compiler again knows exactly what to use, without import.